# how to declare unsigned char array in java?

Tags: java

how to declare an `array` of data type unsigned char in java.

I tried to do `private unsigned char[] Memory = new char[64000];`, but its giving error that `<identifier> expected`

My project says:

   Memory addressing is 16 bits

   Memory is simulated by taking a byte (unsigned char) array of 64K

   All memory references are through Load and Store instructions between Memory and General purpose Registers

   Stack is of 50 bytes for each process

Comment: So what should I do then?

Comment: The question is: What do you even want to do?

Comment: You need to clarify what your project requires. A char is a 16-bit unsigned integer whereas a byte is a signed 8-bit integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A char in Java is always unsigned :

> **[4.2.1. Integral Types and Values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)** 
>   The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges: 
>    ...
>  For char, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535

Therefore, simply write :

```
private char[] Memory = new char[64000];
```

Answer (score 0):

**`char` type in Java according to the JLS is unsigned.**